# Creating an 'alias' or 'symlink' to a separate folder in apache

Tags: symbolic-link, apache-http-server, amazon-ec2, alias

```
-/
|--bin
|--home
  |--user_1
    |--somefile.html
    |--somefile2.html
  |--user_2
    |--differentFile.html
|--var
  |--www
    |--file1.html
```

i want the urls to be `http://serverip/user_1/somefile.html` but right now it only serves files from the "www" folder

any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: While the symlink will work if the user permissions are correct, you may want to look into [user dirs as well](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/public_html.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want users to be able to access `http://serverip/user_1/somefile.html`

Then you would do this

`ln -s /home/user_1 /var/www`

Note that you still have to have proper read permissions set for apache to read the files in /home/user_1

You can also accomplish this in apache configs, take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538572/apache-multiple-documentroot

Comment: or just `ln -s /home/user_1 /var/www` (without the `cd`).  This also assumes the permissions are correct.

Comment: mmhm, changed it

Comment: thanks, sorry for my lack of knowledge with this topic, if i were to add another file, will i have to do 'ln -s newfile.html' again?

Comment: no it references the directory and reflects the directory's present state, not the state it was at when linked